# Parametric types in Java

Tags: java, types

I'm looking at the documentation of *JasperReports* and I do not understand the return type of the following method:

```
public java.lang.Class<?> getValueClass()
```

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class<?>` refers to any instance of Class. As compared to `Class<? extends Collection>` which would narrow the criteria down to a limited group of classes (those that extend `Collection`).

This is particularly important when calling methods like `newInstance`. If you have `Class<?> a` and call `a.newInstance()` you'll get an `Object`. if you have `Class<? extends Collection>` and call `b.newInstance()` you'll get an instance of `Collection`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have one more followup question: why not simply use Class as a return type instead of Class<?>

Comment: I think I already know the answer to that one. Since one wants to define more precisely the return type of some Class methods (such as newInstance), the Class got parameterized with a wildcard type ?.

Comment: You are correct: `Class` and `Class<?>` are synonymous, but `Class<?>` is more precise - it tells the reader that you've actually thought about what kind of `Class` it might be.

Answer (score 3):

The method returns a `Class` object. The `?` indicates that it can be any type of class. You can read more about wildcards [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). These `Class` objects are often utilized when you're dealing with [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).

Answer (score 0):

It just returns an instance of a class. `?` parameter which represents a generic wild card object i.e it is a class of any type.